# How to cache data get from web services for specific time in iOS using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, caching

I am getting a lot of images from web services. I want to cache it. I want to know is there any way to cache data for specific time for example for 1 day.

Comment: You can do this with the Kingfisher library.

Comment: Thanks @Moritz for it

Answer (score 0):

You should use [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage).

```
let downloader = ImageDownloader()
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/image/jpeg")!)

downloader.download(urlRequest) { response in
    print(response.request)
    print(response.response)
    debugPrint(response.result)

    if let image = response.result.value {
        print(image)
    }
}
```

To clear the cache you can see this section: https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage#image-cache